# iCal Outlook Invitation - Description Field Replaced by Email Content with php

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer, icalendar

In PHP, I am trying to send an iCal invitation with Outlook using PHPMailer. The iCal is sent successfully and everything works fine except for the description field, which seems to be overwritten by Outlook and replaced with the email content.

I don't have this issue with google calendar.

```
// My ical code look like this

        $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
            'PRODID:test' . "\r\n" .
            'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
            'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN' . "\r\n" .
            'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
            'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
            'DTSTAMP:'.$date_created."\r\n" .
            'CREATED:' . $date_created .  "\r\n" .
            'LAST-MODIFIED:' . $date_modified .  "\r\n" .
            'DTSTART:' . $date_start . "\r\n" .
            'DTEND:' . $date_end . "\r\n" .
            'DESCRIPTION: I am a comment, hello!' . . "\r\n" .
            'ORGANIZER;CN=' . $from . ':mailto:' . $from_mail .  "\r\n" .
            'UID:' . $uid . "\r\n" .
            'ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;RSVP=FALSE;CN=' . $user_name . ';X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:' . $user_mail . "\r\n" .
            'LOCATION: test street'.  "\r\n" .
            'SEQUENCE:0'. "\r\n" .
            'STATUS:CONFIRMED' .   "\r\n" .
            'SUMMARY:Hello I am a title' . "\r\n" .
            'TRANSP:OPAQUE' . "\r\n" .
            'CLASS:PUBLIC' . "\r\n" .
            'PRIORITY:5' . "\r\n" .
            'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
            'DESCRIPTION:I am a comment, hello!'  . "\r\n" .
            'TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
            'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
            'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
            'END:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
            'TZID:Europe/Paris' . "\r\n" .
            'END:VCALENDAR';
[...]


// then send with something like this

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->setMailerForSystem();
        $mail->From     = $mail_user;
        $mail->FromName = $name_user;
        $mail->Subject  = $subject;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body    = $html_body;
        $mail->AltBody = $alt_body;
        $mail->Ical = $ical;
        $mailer->AddStringAttachment($ical, "Invit", "7bit", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8;");
        $mail->Send();
```

Finaly, the "Invit" file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:test
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20230707T093555Z
CREATED:20230707T093555Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20230707T093555Z
DTSTART:20230708T073900
DTEND:20230708T080900
DESCRIPTION:I am a comment, hello!
ORGANIZER;CN=test test:mailto:mymail@outlook.test
UID:test2-uid
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;RSVP=FALSE;CN=testr testr;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:yourmail@outlook.test
LOCATION: test street
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Hello I am a title
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:I am a comment, hello!
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
TZID:Europe/Paris
END:VCALENDAR
```

So, has anyone already encountered this behavior? Or does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 0):

When sending an iCal invitation to Outlook, do not send it as an attachment. iCal must be the main MIME part of the message with the content type of "text/calendar".